# How to add a 2nd Top Level Menu bar at my Blog/website?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to add a 2nd Top level menu bar at my blog [TechBemaers.com](http://www.techbeamers.com/)

There is already a primary top level menu in the Blog which I want to keep only to display option for Home page, About, contact info and privacy policy.
[image]

So under the 2nd level top menu, I would like to showcase my work area categories like in the attached picture are shown e.g. Blogging, Programming, Alexa, Automation etc.

For your information, I'm using Wordpress 4.2.3 as CMS and using Point Theme from MyThemeShop. Kindly suggest me how can I add this top menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with Wordpress, but here's what I'd do if I were you:

1.Locate which PHP file extracts the arrays of the menu bars. 
2.Follow the structure of the arrays which result to HTML structure.
3.Insert this:
The HTML looks like this.

```
<ul class="my-showcase">
 <li>Blogging</li>
 <li>Programming</li>
 <li>Alexa</li>
 <li>Automation</li>
</ul>
```

Locate the CSS files which it uses, then add this 2 small thingies:

```
.my-showcase{
    width:100%
    height:60px  /*modify your height here*/
}
.my-showcase li{
    display:inline;
}
```

Modify the CSS to your needs. Hope it helps!
Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/t48ncxo2/) demo!